# Can't save any document by Ms-Office [wine]

Tags: microsoft-office, wine, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) and installed Ms-Office by using Wine. Initially Ms-Word and Ms-Excel works fine. But recently not able to save any documents by Ms-Office.

Whenever I try to save or save-as any document of Word and Excel, I am getting following error (every time!):

[image]

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8297134/) is more information on error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of office?

Comment: Have you tried Play On Linux, is it?

Comment: @BigChris No only wine.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it is Ms-Office 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration procedure which helped me to correct problem:

Run **`wincfg`** (either from terminal or by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and select windows version :Windows XP (change from Windows 7 to Windows XP) and then Apply (<kbd>OK</kbd>)to save setting.

[image: Wine configuration]

Now there is no problem with saving documents!

**This solution is worked may be because** I installed Ms-Office 2007 under Windows XP and later change version to Windows 7, so resetting/fixing windows version by `winecfg` solved my problem.

---

Hope others who face such problem with running application under wine can make sure windows version by `wincfg` can solve such problem with windows version changed in case such as mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MS Office 2007. The problem solved, when I installed Service Pack 1 on MS-Office (unfortunately SP2 and SP3 aren't compatible with WINE). After SP1 installation, I am able to save office files.